# JavaFX selecting hexagon

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a game and I have pieces in my GUI that are hexagons. I want to select them when they get clicked on. I tried the following:

```
hexagon.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println(piece.toString());
        }
    });
```

which prints the information about the selected piece if I click on it but the piece itself doesn't get selected (blue border around hexagon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially your code

```
hexagon.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println(piece.toString());
        }
    });
```

is just printing out  whatever "piece" is.

if you want to select the hexagon, you will need to apply the selection within your onMouseClicked Listener's handle method.

The onMouseClicked just listens for mouse clicks, you have to provide it with information about "What to do if clicked."

So in this case you will want to do

```
    hexagon.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println(piece.toString());

hexagon.setStroke(Color.BLUE);  //Color.BLACK, etc, but you asked for BLUE here.
        }
    });
```

The stroke is the outline of the object, so I'm assuming that is what you mean by "selected?"

If you want to select the entire hexagon you would change "setStroke" to "setFill," but you asked for a blue border.

---

I'm also not sure why you have hexagon, as well as "piece," which I thought the hexagons ARE the pieces...?

Depending on what your code is doing, you might replace `hexagon.setStroke(Color.BLUE);` with `piece.setStroke(Color.BLUE);`

Either way, hope this helps!

Comment: My piece is a group which has a image and a hexagon. Thanks for the help. Question: can you make the setStroke border thicker? @Lasagna

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks for the info on that.  For your question.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#strokeWidthProperty

you would want "setStrokeWidth(x.x);  //default is 2.0

Comment: Is it possible to only select one at a time? Because I can't select more than 1 at the same time...

Comment: You can select as many or little as you want.  Update your code, lets ake a look.  you could say something like onMouseClick = selected.  if(selected)  then move.  So you select 3, then it triggers the move.  You need to be able to use the events for each.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide the [code you are using for the hexagon](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a full specification of what you wish to accomplish.  The obvious answer is that you would maintain an internal selection state for the hexagon and just [set a stroke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#setStroke-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-) in code on a hexagon shape or apply a [drop shadow effect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/DropShadow.html), but maybe you would prefer a different approach such as [styling via css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094736/change-javafx-style-class-based-on-model-state) or subclassing [ToggleButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html).  For instance with a toggle button, there are [selected](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html#selectedProperty) and unselected states, as well as [armed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#armedProperty) and unarmed states and [hovered](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470#file-modena-css-L430) and unhovered styles, each of which can have different visual feedback applied.  I could provide a more specific answer, but I'm not sure it would be applicable to your situation. With more specifics you might get a better answer.

Comment: Is it possible to only select one at a time? Because I can't select more than 1 at the same time... @jewelsea

Comment: Yes, you could implement single selection or multiple selection.  How you do so depends upon your implementation method.  Providing a more specific answer is not possible without knowing your code or approach.  I could write something from scratch but if I did so it would both take quite some time and also probably not be exactly what you are looking for either.