# How to mark a selected cell of GridPane using css?

Tags: css, user-interface, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a GridPane, and I wish to have the option of selecting a tile/cell with one mouse click, and for its color to change semi-permanently. Meaning, after one mouse click the color changes from red to blue, and stays that way until I click another tile/cell. Then, the previous tile/cell get's the color red again, and the new tile/cell gets the color blue.

Is there a way to do this using css? Or by code?
I tried the "pressed" command, but all it does is a swift color change.

```
.pane{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.pane:hover{
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.pane: **pressed** { /*Not the result I wanted...*/
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: have you tried :active or :focus

Comment: you need a) logic to keep track of the "selected" b) custom css - f.i. a pseudoClass - to visualize it

Comment: Nor active nor focus did the trick. I eventually did what you said, kleo, and programmed the logic+visualized it.

Comment: Similar sample for logic for selected state + pseudoClass as proposed by kleiopatra: [Change JavaFX style class based on model state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094736/change-javafx-style-class-based-on-model-state)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This piece of code solved it for me:

```
//Note 1: The name of my GridPane was "gPaneWeeklyEvents".
//Note 2: My GripPane was 6x6
private int prevColIndex;
private int prevRowIndex;
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    gPaneWeeklyEvents.getChildren().forEach(item -> {
            item.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
           @Override
           public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
               if (event.getClickCount() == 1) {
                   Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
                   Integer colIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(source);
                   Integer rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(source);
                   if (rowIndex == null) {
                       rowIndex = 0;
                   }
                   if (colIndex == null) {
                       colIndex = 0;
                   }
                   if (rowIndex != prevRowIndex || colIndex != prevColIndex) {
                       gPaneWeeklyEvents.getChildren().get(rowIndex * 6 + colIndex).setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
                       gPaneWeeklyEvents.getChildren().get(prevRowIndex * 6 + prevColIndex).setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
                       prevRowIndex = rowIndex;
                       prevColIndex = colIndex;
                   }
               }
           }
       });
    });
}
```