# Javafx custom pseudo class css parse error

Tags: java, javafx

I have written code using a PseudoClass in java code which is the same as various web examples such as the one in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pseudoClassStateChanged-javafx.css.PseudoClass-boolean-

```
public class SuggestedButton extends Button {
    
    private static final PseudoClass SUGGESTED_PSEUDO_CLASS_STATE = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("suggested");
    
    BooleanProperty suggestedState = new BooleanPropertyBase(false) {

        @Override public void invalidated() {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(SUGGESTED_PSEUDO_CLASS_STATE, get());
       }

        @Override public Object getBean() {
           return SuggestedButton.this;
       }

        @Override public String getName() {
           return "suggestedState";
       }
   };
   
   public void setSuggested(boolean isSuggested) {
        this.suggestedState.set(isSuggested);
      }
}
```

This appears to work fine, however my editor highlights ":suggested" in red in the css file:

```
.btn-apply:suggested {
    -fx-background-color: green;
    background-color: green;
}
```

When I run the program and use a controller that contains a SuggestedButton, I see this warning and the button doesn't change color:

> Dec 26, 2022 4:06:05 PM javafx.css.CssParser declaration WARNING: CSS
> Error parsing '*{btn-apply}: Expected COLON at [1,11]

In my .fxml file I am not setting the versions for javafx:

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
```

I am using javafx version 13 in my dependencies.

Adding

```
System.out.println()
```

shows that the events are firing correctly.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: No need to set `background-color`, that is not a JavaFX CSS attribute (that is not your core issue).

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong.  Provide a [mcve] (this isn't fxml related so no need for FXML, just an Application class, your custom button class, and a CSS file, so all you are really missing is the application which demos the usage).  See this [reference sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094736/change-javafx-style-class-based-on-model-state/36095115#36095115) and try it in your environment.  If it works compare it to your implementation (it looks pretty similar to me).

Comment: The editor may not be smart enough to handle a custom pseudo class, so the red highlighting of the CSS file might be OK.  But the runtime should handle it if correctly setup, so there is an issue here regardless.

Comment: @jewelsea I just set the background-color because it eliminated an IDE warning.

Comment: Found the solution - as is usual it was an oversight. In the fxml for the control, I was setting style="btn-apply" instead of styleClass="btn-apply".

@jewelsea Creating a minimal reproducible example showed that the issue was not with my environment and helped me to look in other directions. If you'd like to create an answer about the value of that exercise, I'd be happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. But regarding "_I just set the background-color because it eliminated an IDE warning_", that is not a warning you should really care about. Your IDE understands Web CSS, as that technology is very widespread, but it likely has very limited support for JavaFX CSS (which is based on Web CSS but not exactly the same). Having `background-color` will do nothing except make the parsing of the CSS file ever-so-slightly slower, because that is not a property associated with any node. All properties in JavaFX CSS are prefixed with `-fx` (except `visibility` for some reason).

Comment: See [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for more information.